# Segmentation Fault using fscanf()

Tags: segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to read a very simple file of data that looks like this:

```
1597 1 0 3 1
```

using the following code:

```
void boot(){
FILE *f = fopen("shutdown.txt", "r");
    uint8_t timestamp = 0;
    uint8_t power_down_type = 0;
    uint8_t power_down_cause = 0;
    uint8_t boot_number = 0;
    uint8_t antenna_deployed = 0;
    uint8_t images_captured = 0;

    fscanf(f, "%u %d %d %d %d %d", &timestamp, &power_down_type, &power_down_cause, &boot_number, &antenna_deployed, &images_captured);

    printf("timestamp: %u\n", timestamp);
    printf("power_down_type: %d\n", power_down_type);
    printf("power_down_cause: %d\n", power_down_cause);
    printf("boot_number: %d\n", boot_number);
    printf("antenna_deployed: %d\n", antenna_deployed);
    printf("images_captured: %d\n", images_captured);
}
```

But when I run the code, I'm getting a SEGV error.

Comment: `"%u"` expect an `unsigned`.  `uint8_t` is not an `unsigned`.  Use `"%hhu"`.  Check `fscanf()` documentation for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` reads an `int` and `%u` reads an `unsigned int`, both of which are bigger than `uint8_t`.  Undefined behavior occurs by writing past the size of the variable.  `%hhu` should be used for `uint8_t`.